# How to flatten a ring shape in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, shapes

I'd like to know whether it is possible to flatten a ring resource drawable (api [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape)). The ring shape, by default is a "correct" circular-like ring, but I want it to become an oval-like one.

This is the shape I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So far, I have achieved the following in Android Studio:

[image]

The above image is a preview of the following xml-code, which defines my shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            >

            <solid android:color="@color/blue_aqua"/>


        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**How to make my ring less circular? How to flatten it? Is it even possible? If not, what do I have to do to achieve the shape I want to achieve (first picture)?**

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use rectangle with corner radius

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Sincerely thank you for your answer. With slight modificatiosn to your code, I've made it work. The only thing I had to change was solid colour of the shape to transparent (#00ffffff), so the inside of the shape is displayed transparent and that way the stroke is the only thing displayed. Thank you very much!

Comment: it was just to give you idea. anyway let me edit the answer. thanks